# how to set color in jcombobox in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jcombobox, netbeans-8

how can change color in combo-box in net-beans.
I'm  Using net-beans IDE version 8.2..

I set background color to [102,102,102] and it doesn't changed correctly like as text-field..

And I set combo-box as editable.. it shows in white color...

is there any alternative ways to do this ?

How can I fix this....

need simple answer.

[image: I get screen shot in User Interface in net-beans]